# How to take pictures from a video with mouse

Tags: python, linux, video, opencv, snapshot

I have a video with cars on a highway, so i would like to cut one by one with the mouse. But i need to do this more automatically, for example, one way to change the frame pressing the space bar and cuting with the mouse and saving the image automatically in a folder.

Have you ever seen something like this for Linux? I'm trying to do in OpenCV, although it isn't necessary.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean by "cut"?  As in, drag a rectangle and save the image inside?

Comment: Can you confirm what you're trying to achieve? Do you mean that, when a vehicle passes a certain static landmark in the movie for example, you want a screen capture / still of the movie taken and saved to a directory?

Comment: @mwcz Yes, drag a rectangle and save the image inside

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have added a code below. It works fine for me. Draw rectangle around object you want to save separately. Press 'Space' to go for next frame.( sometimes you need to press longer to move foreward. i don't know why). Similarly 'Esc' to exit.

usage: python car.py videofile

---

```
# car.py
import cv,sys
print "usage: python car.py <videofile>"

box=[0,0,0,0]
i = 0
global image
#   creating mouse callback function
def my_mouse_callback(event,x,y,flags,param):
    global drawing_box,i
    if event==cv.CV_EVENT_LBUTTONDOWN:
        events = event
        #print event
        drawing_box=True
        [box[0],box[1],box[2],box[3]]=[x,y,0,0]
        print x,y
    if event==cv.CV_EVENT_LBUTTONUP:
        events = event
        drawing_box=False
        events= event
        if box[2]<0:
            box[0]+=box[2]
            box[2]*=-1
        if box[3]<0:
            box[1]+=box[3]
            box[3]*=-1
        rect = (box[0],box[1],box[2],box[3])
        #print rect
        roi = cv.GetSubRect(image,rect)
        filename = str(i)+'.jpg'
        #save(image,rect,filename)
        cv.SaveImage(filename,roi)
        i = i+1 

    if event==cv.CV_EVENT_MOUSEMOVE:
        if (drawing_box==True):
            box[2]=x-box[0]
            box[3]=y-box[1] 


#   function to draw the rectangle, added flag -1 to fill rectangle. If you don't want to fill, just delete it.     
def draw_box(img,box):
    cv.Rectangle(img,(box[0],box[1]),(box[0]+box[2],box[1]+box[3]),(255,0,0),2)

#   main program    
capture = cv.CaptureFromFile(sys.argv[1])
image2 = cv.QueryFrame(capture)
drawing_box=False

#   make a clone of image
temp=cv.CloneImage(image2)

cv.NamedWindow("Box Example")
cv.SetMouseCallback("Box Example",my_mouse_callback,temp)

while(1):
#   global image
    image = cv.QueryFrame(capture)
    while(1):
        roi = 0
        save = False
        events = 0
        boxsaver = 0
        cv.Copy(image,temp)

        if drawing_box==True:
            draw_box(temp,box)

            i = i+1

        cv.ShowImage("Box Example",temp)
        if cv.WaitKey(20)==27:
            sys.exit()
        elif cv.WaitKey(20)==32:
            break
```